# Want to send reminder for the envelope to user;s email

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am integrating the docusing API using docusign python sdk, I have succssfully integrated the create_envelope functionality in my python application and I am able to send the envelope with a document to sign to user's email.

now lets say that user did not sign the document that I have sent and now after 2 weeks I want to send a reminder for that particular envelope and to that user's email.

How I can implement it using python sdk??

I have tried to explre Docusing Python SDK API reference but did not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the **envelope_id** and which recipient(s) you want to remind, then the code in Python is this:

```
api_client = ApiClient()
# You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication method
api_client.set_default_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token)
envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)

envelope_id = '967a1aad-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e162c10e01fc'
envelope = Envelope()
envelope.envelope_id = envelope_id
envelopes_api.update(account_id, envelope_id, envelope=envelope, resend_envelope='true')
```

[See blog post I wrote about this topic](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-resend-your-envelope-programmatically)

**Note:** the term "resend" just means a reminder, it's not really doing it from scratch again, sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: can i add any reminder subject and message with this ???

Comment: It's using the original one for the envelope, not sure it can be updated at this time.  You can try to also modify the subject line and see if it allows you to do that.